# Access VBA: Can you open same record set twice?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I"m opening a record set like so:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(curSKU)
```

Can you open up the same recordset twice with different variables:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(curSKU)

Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(curSKU)
```

Is this allowed? Will it cause problems if I try to iterate through each set at different times using rst.MoveNext, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I've ever done that but yes that will work.   Now you may run into page locking problems if you are updating records in both recordsets.  A 4 Kb Access page can and, usually does, contain multiple records.   If you are adding records then that's less of an issue as Access 2000 and newer, that is Jet 4.0, appears to add new records in individual pages.